# How To Write Content Of uploaded file in another file

Tags: php, file-upload

What I need:

When user upload a file then all content of that file should write into another file.

Here is my code

```
            $.validator.addMethod("custom_phone", function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || value.match(/^[0-9,\+-]+$/);
            }, "Please enter a valid phone number.");

            $("#query").validate(
            {
            rules: { 
            mobile:
            {
            required: true
            },
            email:
            {
            required: true,
            email: true
            },
            name:
            {
            required: true
            }, 


            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) { 
            if (element.parent().hasClass("input-append")){
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            }else{
            error.insertAfter(element);
            } 
            },
            success: function(element) {

            element.closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {

            // $("#feedback").remove();
            //$('#feedback_ajax').removeClass('dis-non');
            var input =$("#query").serialize();
            alert(input);
            var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(input);
            alert(myJsonString);
            //console.log(myJsonString);
            $.ajax({
            url: "{{ DomainDetect() }}/ajax?for=formdata",
            type: "POST",
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: false,
            data: myJsonString,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            },
            error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             return false;
            }

            }).done(function(msg ) {
                console.log(msg);
                data = $.parseJSON(responseData);
                console.log(data);
             $('.8u').empty();
             $('.row flush').append(msg);

            }); 

            }
            });



        <form id= "query" name ="query" class="regform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="row orgrw flush pdfrm">
    <div class="3u"><label>Name</label></div>
    <div class="6u">
    <input class="text txtbx" type="text" name="name">
    </div>
    <div class="3u"><p class="alert alert_name">Required</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row orgrw flush pdfrm">
    <div class="3u"><label>Email</label></div>
    <div class="6u">
    <input class="text txtbx" type="text" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="3u"><p class="alert alert_name">Required</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row orgrw flush pdfrm">
    <div class="3u"><label>Mobile No.</label></div> 
   <div class="6u">
   <input class="text txtbx" type="text" name="mobile">
   </div>
   <div class="3u"><p class="alert alert_name">Required</p></div>
</div>
<div class="row orgrw flush pdfrm">
<div class="3u"><label>Upload resume</label></div>
<div class="6u">
<input class="" type="file" name="file">
</div>
<div class="3u not-mobile">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="row orgrw flush pdfrm">
<div class="3u"><label style="line-height:1em">Any comments<br><span class="ft4">(optional)</span></label></div>
<div class="6u">
<textarea name="s_comment" rows="2" cols="10" style="min-height:6em; overflow:auto; padding:0.5em; font-size:16px; background-color:#f4f4f4; border-radius:0"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="3u not-mobile">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="row orgrw flush pdfrm">
<div class="3u not-mobile">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="6u aligncenter">
<input type="submit" class="attendnow cursr button" value="Submit">
</div>
<div class="3u not-mobile">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</form>
```

php code:

```
            not working:echo $_FILES["file"];

           if(isset($_POST['file']))
            {

            $upload=$_POST['file'];
            $file="uploaddocument.txt";
            if(file_exists($file))
            {
            $current = file_get_contents($upload);
            }
             $sucess=file_put_contents($file, $current);
            }
            else
            {
              echo "fie not uploaded";
            }
```

Output:

```
Array(
    ["name"] => Deepak
    [email] => dpk.pandit1992@gmail.com
    [mobile] => 919871077792
    [s_comment] => "fesgdtfd"
)
```

Error.log

```
      Undefined index: file
```

Problem I am facing is that I am not able to write the content of upload file data in another file.

Comment: do you write code like this? it is totally unreadable please try to indent your code properly, it is very helpful (believe me)

Comment: ok bansi thank for suggestion but resolve my issue

Comment: And where is the code that is processing the file? I mean, your php code? If you don't have it no one here will do it for you. So start to read about how to upload a file on google, write some code to test it and then you go back here if you face a problem that you can not solve.

Comment: sr i have updated my php code

Comment: my query  not working:echo $_FILES["file"]; is still not working

Comment: eror log file  Undefined index: file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [tutorial on file uploads with AJAX](http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax). Be aware that only newer browsers support this feature, check caniuse.com for [details which browsers work](http://caniuse.com/#search=FormData).

Sidenote: as stated above: get a decent IDE like PHPStorm or similar, it will help you to greatly improve your code.

Comment: thank for solution i have tried  but  formadata is not working in ie 8,9,10 please help me in this issue.

Comment: Check out [moxie](https://github.com/moxiecode/moxie), it's a polyfill for file uploads.